# simple loop not working for random numbers

Tags: c++, loops, double, long-integer

I am a programming newbie. I needed a simple function to convert any number with decimal point X.YZ into XYZ. I did it by multiplying it by 10 enough times and using *double* to *int* conversion.

---

```
  int main()
  {
    std::cout << "Number: " << std::endl;
    double a;
    // the uninitialized b was pointed out, its not the issue
    long b = 0;

    std::cin >> a;

       while(b!=a)
             {
              a*=10;
              b=a;
             }

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

---

This works like 90 percent of the time. For some numbers like 132.54, the program runs infinitely long.  It processes 132.547(which should use more memory then 132.54) the way it should.

So my question is : Why is it not working 100 percent for the numbers in the memory range of long int? Why 132.54 and similar numbers?

I am using Codeblocks and GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: variable definitions inside functions are not initialized with default values, so your b variable contains random value.

Comment: That will be solved after the first round, and doesn't explain why the loop would run forever.

Comment: Obligatory [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many decimal floating point numbers cannot be exactly represented in binary. You only get a close approximation.

If 132.54 is represented as 132.539999999999999, you will never get a match.

Print the values in the loop, and you will see what happens.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. How do I do this properly then?

Comment: @StanislawT there is no "properly".

Comment: @StanislawT As an alternative approach I suggest you convert the input to a string and remove the dot manually.

Comment: @jrok or the comma. use the locale facets... Easy :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you never initialize `b` and therefore have *undefined behaviour*.

You should do this:

```
 long b = 0;
```

Now you can go compare b with something else and get good behaviour.

Also comparing a `float` with an `integral` type should be done like comparing to an appropriate epsilon value:

```
 while(fabs(an_int - a_float) < eps)
```

Comment: not undefined, just indeterminate (see _Initializers_, dcl.init)

Comment: The behavior persists even after proper initialization.

Comment: Wrong- it is indeed UB to read an uninitialized primitive type.

Comment: @phresnel: The value may be indeterminate, but reading the value itself is already UB.

Comment: While this may be technically correct, it has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: @PeteBecker what are you talking about? Everything after that while comparison of OP's code is UB land. It has **everything** to do with the problem!

Comment: @phresnel There is no indeterminate behaviour. There are indeterminate values. Most uses of uninitialized variables (including this one) have undefined behaviour. See §4.1.

Comment: @TonyTheLion - try it. Does the problem go away if `b` is initialized? Undefined behavior doesn't mean that bad things **must** happen. It means only what it says: the language definition does not tell you what happens. In this case, the effect is benign.

Comment: Gosh, I'd give this another down vote for the new edit. Yes, adding an artificial definition of equality **might** make the symptoms go away, but it doesn't fix the underlying incorrect assumption. There's nothing inherently wrong with comparing a floating-point value with an integral value, so switching to **nearly equal** must be part of an overall design, not a hack to work around a misunderstanding.

Comment: **nearly equal** is about as good as it gets with floating point numbers.  Just saying.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Are you refering to [conv.lval]? (sidenote: I didn't mean to say "indeterminate behaviour" as standardese, just "indeterminate values" and thus "indeterminate behaviour" in non-standardese)

Comment: @PeteBecker now what exactly would you change about the design of OP's code to make it better?

Comment: @TonyTheLion - I don't know. It's not clear to me what the purpose of the code is, which is why I asked about that in a comment to a different answer. You have to know where you're going before you try to figure out how to get there.

Comment: @TonyTheLion - no, **nearly equal** is not as good as it gets with floating-point numbers. In fact, it's usually a response from people who don't understand the problems that they're running into, and it usually just adds to their problems.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that most decimal values cannot be represented exactly as floating-point values. So having a decimal value that only has a couple of digits doesn't guarantee that multiplying by ten enough times will produce a floating-point value with no fractional part. To see this, display the value of `a` each time through the loop. There's lots of noise down in the low bits.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. Never realized that. So how do I do it for those numbers?

Comment: @StanislawT - how do you do **what**? Be clear on what your requirements are. The solution to the example you gave seems to be to multiply by 100 then round to the nearest integer. More generally, though, where do these numbers come from? If they start out as text and you need to remove the decimal point, that's easy; no floating-point involved. Just remove the decimal point.

Comment: I need the user to be able to input any random number processable within the memory range of double(which is 64bit if im correct). Then the result would be used for further calculations and those are multiplying and dividing.

Comment: @StanislawT - yes, double is typically 64 bits these days -- a 53-bit fraction (which includes 1 implicit bit), an 11-bit exponent, and 1 bit for the sign. But when someone types in a number, say 6.02e23, what do you want to change it to?

Comment: Honestly. I do not know that yet. The issue is getting too complicated for my level.I will try solving my thing with strings for now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading it as a double, read it as a string and parse it. You won't run into floating precision problem that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
long b;
```

Here you *define* `b`. From this point, the variable contains garbage value. The value can be absolutely random, basically it's just what happened to be in the memory when it was allocated.  After that you are using this variable in a condition:

```
 while(b!=a)
```

This will lead to *undefined behaviour*, which basically means that anything can happen, including an opportunity that the app will seem to be working (if you are lucky), based on the garbage value that is in `b`.

To avoid this, you will need to initialize the `b` with some value, for example, `long b = 0`.

Comment: There's no such thing as undetermined behavior, it's either undefined behavior or unspecified behavor, but not what you say.  In this case it's just UB.

Comment: Regardless, the problem isn't here; it's the underlying assumption that multiplying by ten enough times will eventually lead to a value with no fractional part.

Comment: I did, and still, nothing has changed. The number 132.54 persists to run infinitely.

Comment: @Stan, @ratzip, of course it runs infinetely, if you pass it a number that can not accurately be represented by `float`, you will never get a match because the value will b like `132.53(9)` in your case.